# Trying to predict the number of abandoned phone calls based on the number of inbound calls.

Tags: statistics

I don't know if this is the best place for this question, but I can't think of anywhere else. Also, my math brain does not work very well, so I'm looking for help from people better at this stuff than I am.

I have a helpdesk phone system. I can track inbound calls, and how many were abandoned (see table below).

I originally thought that the relationship between the inbound calls and the abandoned calls would be constant. If I expected the abandon rate to be 10% then if we had 100 calls in a week, the abandoned calls would be 10. If we only had 10 calls in a week, we'd only have 1 abandoned call. But this is clearly not how it's working.

I notice in these stats that the percentage of abandoned calls is not constant. As the number of inbound calls rises, so does the rate of abandoned calls. This makes sense to me. But the percentage of abandoned calls does not seem to rise in proportion to the number of calls.

How can I calculate the relationship between the increase in call numbers and the increased abandon rate? I'm sure there should be a way for me to predict the number of abandoned calls based on the number of inbound calls.

[image]

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, are you asking that you need to calculate the percentage by which inbound calls increased (or decreased) as compared to the previous row?

Comment: Not quite. When I first started tracking these numbers I expected the percentage of abandoned calls to be constant. If I expected the abandon rate to be 10% then if we had 100 calls in a week, the abandoned calls would be 10. If we only had 10 calls in a week, we'd only have 1 abandoned call.
But this is clearly not how it's working. I'm sure there is a relationship between the total number of calls in one week and how many of them were abandoned, but I can't get my head around what that relationship is.
I should edit my question for better clarity.

Comment: so do you need a relationship between the inbound calls and the percentage (of abandoned calls) or abandoned calls?

Comment: In exploratory data analysis graphs are your friend.  Plot everything against everything else.  Something may click.  This sort of data has a *lot* of noise in it, so looking at the numbers can mislead you.  You might expect the percentage of abandons to rise as the number of calls increases because the wait time increases and more people get frustrated.  If you have wait time and wait time when people abandon data you should add it in.

Comment: Yes, I need a relationship between the inbound calls and the abandoned calls. I thought the percentage might give me that, but clearly, it doesn't :(

I like @RossMillikan suggestion and will look into these graphs.

Comment: If the spreadsheet is Excel, then I suggest you do a scatter-point plot of the abandons vs Inbounds. You can then have it best fit a function to the data (the more data points you have, the better - the few you show in the question may not be sufficient for good results). (I'm sure you can do this on other spreadsheets as well, but I am not familiar with them>)